# I want to create space between the JLabel(s) and align the JButtons to be on the same line

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I've created a registration page in Java using different Layouts and I'm having trouble aligning the buttons on the same line and creating space between each JLabel.You can see it on the link (https://postimg.org/image/jaur8rxz7/).
This is the code that I have written

```
package liblog;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Aregistration extends JFrame {

 private JTextField text;
 private JTextField text2;
 private JPasswordField pass;
 private JButton log1;
 private JButton sign1;
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
 JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
 JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
 JLabel label2 = new JLabel();

 Aregistration(){
     super("Admin Registration");
     setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,15,15));
     setBounds(500,500,500,250);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     Container con = this.getContentPane();
     con.add(panel);
     panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


     label1=new JLabel("First Name");
     label1.setToolTipText("Enter Your First Name");
     text = new JTextField("Name",20);

     label2=new JLabel("Registration No");
     label2.setToolTipText("Enter Your Registation no");
     text2 = new JTextField("Registation No",20);


     label3 = new JLabel("Password");
     label3.setToolTipText("Enter Your Password");
     pass = new JPasswordField("Password",20);


     log1 = new JButton("Log In");
     sign1 = new JButton("Register");


     panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 0)));
     panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(HEIGHT));
     panel.add(label1);
     panel.add(text);

     panel.add(label2);
     panel.add(text2);

     panel.add(label3);
     panel.add(pass);


    panel.add(log1);
    panel.add(sign1);


     setVisible(true);

 }
 public static void main(String[]args){new Aregistration();

 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm having trouble aligning the buttons on the same line

Create a second panel and add the buttons to the panel and then add this panel to your main panel:

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
buttonPanel.add( log1 );
buttonPanel.add( Box.createHorizontalStrut(5) );
buttonPanel.add( sign1 );
panel.add( buttonPanel );
```

> and creating space between each JLabel

You can also use a vertical strut.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Thanks.But i didn't use BoxLayout because it gave an error that said I can't use two BoxLayouts.I used FlowLayout instead and it worked.

Comment: Do you realize that `Box.createHorizontalStrut(5)` creates layout that is not portable?

Comment: @JanBodnar, in what way? That is a class of the JDK.

Comment: @camickr The layout is not portable. Value 5 is in pixels. 5px space between buttons might be OK on 1280x720 but it won't work on say 1920x1080. For this situations,`MigLayout` has logical pixels and `GroupLayout` indirect gaps `related`, `unrelated`. To create visual layouts that look good on different screens, we cannot set gaps in pixels. Old layout managers from the 90s do not work anymore.